# SSL Client in Java

Tags: ssl-client-authentication

I want to create SSL client in java. I have 3 files provided by SSL Server namely:
1. Server's public key : CAfile.pem
2. Client's private key : client.pem
3. Client's public  key : client.crt

Using client's private and public keys, i have created 1 keystore which is a pkcs12 file and using Server's public key i have created 1 truststore which is a JKS file.
Then i'm setting following system properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType","pkcs12");                            
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",<keystorepath>);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",<password>);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",<truststorepath>);                         
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",<password>);
```

And, part of my code for TLS handshake is:

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(new KeyManager[0], new TrustManager[] {new DefaultTrustManager()},     new SecureRandom());
SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);

SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
sslSocket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(socket,socketHost,port,true);
sslSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
sslSocket.startHandshake();
```

But, while doing handshake, i'm getting following error.

```
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1705)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:122)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:972)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ClientHandshaker.java:1087)
at     sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1006)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:285)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
at com.integra.socket.TestSocket.connectToSocket(TestSocket.java:107)
at com.integra.socket.TestSocket.main(TestSocket.java:57)
```

Please do help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the info that you provided seems that the problem is similar to the ones reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780673/cause-of-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33643652/socket-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035785/java-error-software-caused-connection-abort-recv-failed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126607/official-reasons-for-software-caused-connection-abort-socket-write-error).